# codeigniter 3 query error handling

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, error-handling, codeigniter-3

I'm in the process of migrating a CI2 project to CI3.

One thing I am having difficulties with is handling errors on db queries. Could someone please tell me the correct way to do this as I cannot seem to find the answer in the docs or previous SO questions.

Basically, if the query results in a sql error i want to return `false`. At the moment it seems that `error()` returns an array and so is always returning true regardless of whether there is an error or not meaning my method always returns false.

```
function get_post()
{
    $post = //some db call to get a post

    if ( $this->db->error() )
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return $post
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Handling Errors**

```
$this->db->error();
```

If you need to get the last error that has occurred, the error() method will return an array containing its code and message.

Here’s a quick example:

```
if ( ! $this->db->simple_query('SELECT `example_field` FROM `example_table`')) {
    $error = $this->db->error(); // Has keys 'code' and 'message'
}
```

1 : Changes in **config/database.php**

```
'db_debug' => FALSE,
```

2:

```
function get_post() {

    $post = //some db call to get a post

    $error = $this->db->error();

    if ( ! empty($error['code'])) {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return $post;
    }
}
```